# Tool that lets me import cookies to Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows, web-development, cookies, microsoft-edge

Are there any tools like [EditThisCookie](http://www.editthiscookie.com/) for Chrome, but for Microsoft Edge?

*EditThisCookie* has the ability to let you export, import, edit specific cookies, and so on. It's so easy to use when you want to edit the values of the cookies to fasten up development and testing, and Edge so far supports manual editing; I can copy settings and it'll copy in CSV format, but sadly if I had data cookies that is already in CSV, I can't copy and paste it into the cookies table in the developer console, and doing so manually can sometimes be a very time consuming process to do.

Is there any way to do so with a program? *Internet Explorer* used to have import and export functionality for cookies too, but I can't find that in MS Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Edge now has a [TamperMonkey plugin](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/tampermonkey/9nblggh5162s?cid=msft_web_collection). Tampermonkey supports a [Wireshark cookie injector](https://github.com/ihciah/cookieinjector):

> Setup: use https://github.com/ihciah/cookieinjector/blob/master/CookieInjector.user.js or simply copy file content to a new script in tampermonkey.
>
> Usage: Use some filters like http.cookie in wireshark and right click on some packets, copy cookie as value
>
> Open a new tab(u'd better open a private window in firefox or something similar called incognito tab in chrome)
>
> Open the site you want to inject cookie in, after finished press Alt+C, paste cookie and fillin the domain, and click OK.
>
> Refresh the page, you should see the cookie has been successfully applied:)
>
> Some tips: When filling in domains, you should write .+root domain